# From where can we decide collection name in use of "sails-mongoose" package, in node.js + sailsjs?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, sails.js

I had code for Connection with mongo with username, password, host, DBName etc in adapter.js,
schema in model,
and for CRUD we can code in controller. but from where can we select particular collection of selected DB of mongo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am the creator of **Sails-mongoose**. I've not really continued my work with sails-mongoose because to use `mongoose`, you will have to cut out `Waterline` which is built completely into the eco system of Sailsjs.

I would recommend using against the library i myself built.

[Apologies & Thanks](https://twitter.com/ktkaushik/status/380592073482588160)