# How to embed and write mongo objects in Sails.js (more than one level deep)?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, sails.js

From sails.js example,

// Person.js

```
   var Person = {
      attributes: {
        firstName: 'STRING',
        lastName: 'STRING',
        age: {
          type: 'INTEGER',
          max: 150,
          required: true
        }
        birthDate: 'DATE',
        phoneNumber: {
          type: 'STRING',
          defaultsTo: '111-222-3333'
        }
        emailAddress: {
          type: 'email', // Email type will get validated by the ORM
          required: true
        }
      }
    };
```

Now how would I add emailAddress to have a home and office  as embedded fields?

Tried to do it this way:

```
emailAddress: {   {

                        work: {
                            type: 'email',
                        },
                        personal: {
                            type: 'email',
                        }
                  }
             },
```

and

```
emailAddress: {  
                     attributes: {

                        work: {
                            type: 'email',
                        },
                        personal: {
                            type: 'email',
                        }
                  }
             },
```

both don't work.   I get errors such as "No Rules found for attributes" for the second case, "Unexpected token  { " in the first case.

Comment: You could use the type json at emailAddress definition inside Person, and then use injectors to manually validate the desired structure.

This will probably be solved in the future by waterline, but until then this should cover your issue

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Ok, Following through some threads on this.
It seems Sails Waterline has no support for embedded MongoDB schema at this stage.
You can write your own contribution or force it, but the out of box support (model validation) etc. need to be hacked too.
https://github.com/balderdashy/sails-mongo/issues/44

The other option - sails-mongoose is unfortunately not supported too.
[From where can we decide collection name in use of "sails-mongoose" package, in node.js + sailsjs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19511047/from-where-can-we-decide-collection-name-in-use-of-sails-mongoose-package-in)

**Update**.
Starting with V0.10, Sails is supporting associations. Perhaps that will make it work. Still experimental.

**Update**.
With the associations functionality you can force a schema in different models and create references between them, but so far it doesn't seem like you'll be able to embed them - only relate them from different collections/tables.

Comment: Sails-mongo doesn't allow specifying a schema for embedded documents

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/balderdashy/sails-mongo/issues/44

It seems they already have it planned as a Feature Request.