# Modeling an ownership relation with Waterline in Sails

Tags: sails.js, waterline

I read about one-to-many association in Sails (v0.10) but I'm wondering if it matches my data model cases:
a "Game" is composed of several "Items". An item is owned by and only by one Game, so when a Game is destroyed, all its items must of course be destroyed.

Is the "one-to-many" association is the good track for my data modeling, or is exist a more proper way to modeling an ownership relation in sails?

EDIT:
Ok, from what I understand [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21173465/how-to-embed-and-write-mongo-objects-in-sails-js-more-than-one-level-deep), Sails Waterline does not supports embedded documents, and it seems those structures would ideally fit for my needs. Anyway, let's go for waterline one-to-many assocations, then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, "ownership" can be conceptually thought of a one-to-many. Object Foo owns a collection of bars. So you'd model Foo (one) --> Bar (many).

In Waterline, this would be:

```
// Foo.js
bars: {
  collection: 'Foo'
}

// Bar.js
parent: {
  model: 'Bar'
}
```

You can query Foo's bars like so:

#### REST

```
/foo/<id>/bars
```

#### Javascript

```
Foo.find().populate('bars')
```